# Integrate $\int \Gamma(a,f(y)) dy $?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, gamma-function

I tried to simplfy my equation  $\int_{0}^{\infty }  \frac{\Gamma(a, \frac{a}{b} x^{2/n})) }{\Gamma(a)(x+1)} {d}x$ with a manipulation of $\frac{1}{1+x} dx =dy $. The integral turns the form as follows
$$  \frac{1}{\Gamma(a)} \int_{0}^{\infty }  \Gamma(a, \frac{a}{b} {(e^y -1)}^{2/n}))  {d}y$$

where $0 < n< 2$, $a>1$, $b>0$. Lets say $f(y) = {(e^y -1)}^{2/n} $. Then, the integral turns to $$ \frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_{0}^{\infty } \Gamma(a,f(y)) dy $$
I found that $\int \Gamma(a,y) dy == y \Gamma(a,y) - \Gamma(a+1,y)$.  How can I implement this to my equation $\int \Gamma(a,f(y)) dy $ ?

I will be grateful for all comments and suggestion.  Thanks a lot!